# Python Error Code

Tags: python, numpy

**So I am trying to average every 600 lines. I am getting a Python error index out of range and the numbers aren't coming out correctly. Help?**

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('Y:/Canopy/PSUone.txt', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 0)
shape = np.shape(data)
data_you_want = data[:,3]
daily_averages = list()

for i,d in enumerate(data_you_want):
    if (i % 600) == 0:
        avg_for_day = np.mean(data_you_want[i - 600:i])
        daily_averages.append(avg_for_day)

with open('Y:/Canopy/newPSUone.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Wind U Direction\n')
    f.write('------------------\n')
    for i, d in enumerate(data_you_want):
         s = '{0:4.3f}\n'. format(daily_averages[i])
         f.write(s)

f.close()
```

Comment: how your input file look like??, update to ur post

Comment: `data_you_want = data[:,3]` gives error > TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Side note, when i is 0, i %0 will be true, and so you will be averaging rows -600:0 which may not be what you want.

Comment: @ForceBru ... that syntax works fine with Numpy. `data` is not a list.

Comment: @VivekSable, `f` is a file handler, isn't it?

Comment: @ForceBru - Yes, and it's already closed by the `with` statement.

Comment: @kindall, yep, didn't notice that

Comment: According to me no need of `f.close()` withside of with statement. file will closed when code come out of `with` statement.

Comment: 1,79376.00,244.9187037, -1.8405,  5.5024, -0.1700, 32.0300
The data reads in like this and i want the 4th column

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `data`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're running into is this bit:

```
for i,d in enumerate(data_you_want):
    if (i % 600) == 0:
        avg_for_day = np.mean(data_you_want[i - 600:i])
        daily_averages.append(avg_for_day)
```

... followed by this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data_you_want):
     s = '{0:4.3f}\n'. format(daily_averages[i])
     f.write(s)
```

Because you're only taking every 600th line from `data_you_want` to average into `daily_averages`, you are going to have `len(data_you_want) // 600` elements in `daily_averages`.  If you iterate over `data_you_want` and try to take `daily_average[i]`, then you are going to reach a point where `i` is greater than the length of `daily_averages` and you'll get an error.